How to Automatically Select the Highest Quality YouTube Thumbnail with 'react-lite-youtube-embed'
I'm using the react-lite-youtube-embed library to embed YouTube videos on my site. However, I'm running into an issue with the resolution of the video thumbnails. I want to ensure that the highest quality thumbnail available is used as the poster image.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
<LiteYouTubeEmbed
  id={videoId}
  poster={resolution}
/>

To address this, I've come up with the following workaround:
// CSS import
import 'react-lite-youtube-embed/dist/LiteYouTubeEmbed.css';

// React imports
import { useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

const Video = ({ videoId }) => {
    const [resolution, setResolution] = useState("maxresdefault");

    const handleError = () => {
        // Fallback to a lower resolution thumbnail
        setResolution("hqdefault");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Image
                src={`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/maxresdefault.jpg`}
                height={0}
                width={0}
                onError={handleError}
            />
            <LiteYouTubeEmbed
                id={videoId}
                poster={resolution}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Video;

This approach initially attempts to load the maxresdefault thumbnail and falls back to the hqdefault thumbnail if the higher resolution image is unavailable.
Question
Is there a more efficient or reliable way to achieve this? Ideally, I want to avoid manual fallbacks and have the component automatically select the highest quality available thumbnail (without fetching the data).
What did I try?
I tried preloading the highest resolution thumbnail (maxresdefault) using an  component from next/image. If the high-resolution thumbnail fails to load, I use the onError handler to switch to a lower resolution (hqdefault).
What was I expecting?
I was hoping for a more seamless way to automatically select the highest quality available thumbnail without relying on manual fallbacks or extra components. Ideally, I want the react-lite-youtube-embed component to handle this internally (without fetching the data).

I have never tried this plugin but have done this with youtube data api, and it does provide "maxres" url in response. checkout this link -> Youtube Data . What do you mean by handle internally without fetching data? Do you mean your app with create thumbnail of video on youtube without fetching data?

Thanks for your response, Mrigayan! By handling it internally, I meant avoiding the use of the YouTube API key and instead using the URL format https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoId}/maxresdefault.jpg.

as that is a third party library not created by google you may want to ask the developer in question lite-youtube-embed   By going around YouTube api you may be also going against the TOS,
